# Regular expressions in python to javascript

Tags: javascript

How to convert the regular expression in the function below which I have done in python to javascript?

```
def data_validation(str):
    r=re.compile('[0-9]{3}/[0-9]{2,3}')
    if len(str)==7 or len(str)==6:
        if r.match(str):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet matches the passed regex literal in javascript and returns false if it is not a match (incidentally your python function will not return a value when the string is not 6 or 7 characters in length).

```js
function data_validation(str) {
  if ((str.length == 7) || (str.length == 6)) {
    if (str.match(/[0-9]{3}\/[0-9]{2,3}/)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

alert(data_validation("555/12"));
alert(data_validation("hello"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python, but I guess the JavaScript equivalent is

```
function data_validation(str) {
    if (str.length == 7 || str.length == 6)
        return /[0-9]{3}\/[0-9]{2,3}/.test(str);
}
```